# ADB doesn't see my device

Tags: android, driver, adb

Unable to install the drivers for the usb debugging mode on android-system.
The device — Sony Xperia V with Android 4.3, on the PC — Windows 7 Home Premium.
Phone Information in Device Manager. There he defined as "portable device". Sorry for language. It is russian :(

[image: Xperia V]

I downloaded the latest ADB drivers from the sit Google, set them manually, and the picture is as follows:

[image: ADB]

ADB does not see the phone.

Update the Windows driver does not, on the grounds that the best of everything is already.
[image: WPD]

If remove them when you reconnect a Windows device starts again instantly put all the same his driver.
Disable automatic driver installation failed. In the Home version of Widnows is only possible to disable autostart them with auto-update service, which I did. Set gpedit.msc, where he was to be an item on the prohibition of automatic installation of the device, but it was not there.

You can connect your phone is turned off debug mode and then turn it on. In the Device Manager list is updated, but nothing new in it does not appear.

I faced with this problem for a long time ago when I try to install a custom recovery . Then the phone just was not detected, probably due to lack of drivers. Tried in vain to fix anything, but it was easier to use someone else's car, where the driver got up at once as it should. Now, the problem still want to overcome, for debugging applications on android-emulator inconvenient, it would be nice to do it several times on a real device.

[image]

Now I don't know what to do :( Help me please.

Comment: Enabled USB Debugging on your phone?

Comment: Yes, USB debugging mode on my phone is enabled.

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the [PC Companion](http://support.sonymobile.com/de/tools/pc-companion/) from Sony.